# Why were there no communications with Aniara?

Tags: movie, aniara

Generally the attempts at hard science fiction in this film were very impressive, as were the sociological aspects. I honestly found it difficult to find plot holes. The realistic treatment of time scales was a breath of fresh air in a genre filled with FTL magic. Through the many obstacles, most questions about science and technology were suitably answered. But the one thing I never heard mentioned was

> why the ship never received nor transmitted one communication to or from Earth or Mars.

The poem does show these attempts:

> we spread the call-sign Aniara wide
> in glass-clear boundlessness, but picked up nothing
> Though space-vibrations faithfully bore round
> our proud Aniara’s last communiqué

The ending absolutely floored me, and explains why eventually this would be impossible. It seems that at some point it would allow some kind of plan to be developed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was stated at the start of the film (as part of the general *worldbuilding* in the first act) that communications with both Earth and Mars would be suspended **for the duration of the voyage**.

> *"All communications systems will be down until we've reached our destination*".

No specific reason is given for this, but it would appear that it has something to do with the ship's drive systems (hinted at later in the film) rather than anything to do with damage to the ship during the accident.

---

In the [original poem](https://gsproject.edublogs.org/gs-texts/texts-used-in-2017/aniara-by-harry-martinson-3/) it seems to be handwaved away as part of the accident;

> We lay in dead space, but to our good fortune
>   the gravitation-works were still in service,
>   and heating elements as well as lighting
>   were not disabled.
>
> **Of other apparatus some was damaged
>
>   and other parts less damaged could be mended.**
>   Our ill-fate now is irretrievable.
>   But the mima will hold (we hope) until the end.

or maybe just as part and parcel of the way in which the ship moves through space, via the magic of "*field egression*".

> Goldonder [Spaceship] Aniara shuts, the siren gives the wail
>   for field-egression by the known routine
>   and then the gyrospinner sets in towing
>   the goldonder upward to the zenith light,
>   where magnetrinos blocking field-intensity
>   soon signal level-zero and field-release occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Considering an average distance to Mars of 100Mio km’s and the approximated travel time of +23 days, we talk about a speed of ~110000 km/h which is not out-of-reach even with todays technologies. And by those technologies, I see no reason why communication would be impossible. Even with a new kind of propulsion that would cut-off communication when running, let’s keep in mind that the accident rendered propulsion offline. So, from a scientific standpoint, that situation is ridiculous. Also the fact, that Aniara obviously dumped all it’s (nuclear) fuel, so, how is life support, artificial gravity and all the shiny attractions powered instead? Solar panels? Ahh, no. And I think when humanity mastered artificial gravity, we may have developed the one or other reliable way of communication. But science aside, don’t you think a trip of so many people (by the size of the ship certainly a good ten-thousands) wouldn’t be properly supervised from either Mars or Earth? No communication would be necessary for them to understand that something went wrong. I’m sliding back to science when I assume, that a vessel of that size would maintain several back-up systems so that no single in-bus screw shouldn’t cause that much of a damage also not an entire stock of them:-)

Anyway, all this leaves room for a thought that this journey went the way it does by intention. Earth is devastated, and the way Mimarobe spoke about Mars in an enraged moment, it seems to me this is not a place worth living for either. If, with all the technology at their hand, a trip to Mars still takes 23 days, other solar systems seem far out of reach. Maybe this was an experiment? Why would a simple transport ship (even a luxury one) have alge plants for Oxygen supply, if I don’t think for the long run? Mima itself, what for on a trip of 23 days – as shown in the “First hour” there was pretty much no interest. A full-featured swimming pool on a space ship? What the f… - assuming capitalism is still our social order, I’m not sure that ever becomes standard.

However, obviously nobody from the crew seemed to be involved in that plan even though the inner circle came-up quick with the realization, this will become a long journey. Why? Because it’s now customary that humanity would do nothing the rescue a good ten-thousands of their fellows? A ship of that size is undetectable when off-heading? There is nothing Earth’s hangar has to offer that can catch-up to a dream-liner with no propulsion? Hard to believe.

Even today experiments are on the way to discover how people behave in the claustrophobia of a space ship or the certainly limited supplies available when taking on Mars. Extreme situation, extreme measures and considering Earth’s condition shown in the intro, humanities future is at stake. An here is a theory for the Spear – it’s quite likely to me, the Spear might have been detected already from Earth or Mars, this way understanding it’s extra-terrestial and Aniara was silently sent out for a first contact… far away enough from Earth to take measures, if this contact doesn’t go as expected. And finally, hopefully enough DNA material is sent to a distant future to leave a footprint in space.

What are you folks think about this?

And sorry, English is not my native language.

Comment: Is this an answer, a comment, or a question?

Comment: I think a bit of all and maybe this thread is not the best place for it. For an answer see it like this: considering all this was initially planned, why would communication even necessary? Thus, having a technical explanation for no communication at all seems to fit the purpose of leaving the fate of the vessel in the hands of the people living there.

Comment: This answer doesn't address the question asked. It appears to be more of a comment about real-world long-distance communications.

Comment: @user14111 - I think the word you're looking for is 'rant'

Comment: All right, waste of time but thanks for a new word in my English vocabulary!